# how to decrypt SHA512 hash value to an actual string in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I encrypt the password by following code

```
HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = null;
hashAlgorithm = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
try 
{
    byte[] byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    byte[] hashValue = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= hashValue.Length - 1; i++) 
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", hashValue[i]);
    }

    return Convert.ToString(sb);
} 
catch 
{
    throw;
}
```

after that I saved it in database.
now I want to retrieve actual password by decrypting it. please help me

Comment: You've misunderstood what a hash does. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: A smart guy said: "How to get a living cow out of the beefburger?".

Comment: Another issue is that a normal cryptographic hash like SHA-2 is not what you want to do for password hashing. You want a slow salted hash instead. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.se for details.

Answer (score 2):

You `hash` a password and you don't `encrypt` it. That being said you cannot `decrypt` it.

Taken from [here](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/)

> Encryption transforms data into another format in such a way that only
> specific individual(s) can reverse the transformation. It uses a key,
> which is kept secret, in conjunction with the plaintext and the
> algorithm, in order to perform the encryption operation. As such, the
> ciphertext, algorithm, and key are all required to return to the
> plaintext.

while

> Hashing serves the purpose of ensuring integrity, i.e. making it so
> that if something is changed you can know that it’s changed.
> Technically, hashing takes arbitrary input and produce a fixed-length
> string that has the following attributes:
>
> 1. The same input will always produce the same output.
> 2. Multiple disparate inputs should not produce the same output.
> 3. **It should not be possible to go from the output to the input.**
> 4. Any modification of a given input should result in drastic change to the hash.
>
> Hashing is used in
> conjunction with authentication to produce strong evidence that a
> given message has not been modified. This is accomplished by taking a
> given input, encrypting it with a given key, hashing it, and then
> encrypting the key with with the recipient’s public key and signing
> the hash with the sender’s private key.

*then what can I use with which I can convert output to input?*

You should decrypt your data and not hash them. Encrypting and Decrypting data is a big subject. A good starting point is to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Generally, you have two types of encryoption, symmetric and assymmetric. So initially, read about them and then choose the one you think is suits your needs. Then try to implement it. You will make use of algorithms that are already implemented in .NET and can be used instantiating objects of the corresponding classes and calling specific methods.

However, I have to make a note here. Usually, we hash the passwords and we don't encrypt them. This is more secure. Taken from [here](http://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374):

> Though hashing and encryption both provide valuable capabilities, for
> the vast majority of situations, *there is only one right option for*
> *storing user passwords for an online application: hashing*. **This is a**
> **one-way function** in which **a hashed value cannot be reversed to obtain**
> **the original input value** (i.e., the password). Symmetric encryption is
> based on the use of an encryption key and is a reversible operation.
> Anyone possessing the key can decrypt an encrypted value to obtain the
> original value.

Comment: then what can I use with which I can convert output to input?

Comment: If ur seriously asking this, read this answer again. Otherwise google for bruteforce or dictionary attack.

Comment: Implementing secure symmetric encryption after only reading MSDN documentation is practically impossible. The API is very low level, so the programmer needs to implement several pitfalls which requires quite a bit of crypto knowledge.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I agree 100% with you. However, it is a starting point, in order he get a base knowledge and then proceed. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Christos People starting that way usually end up with encryption code that appears to work but isn't secure. I'd recommend starting with either technical background to learn about all the pitfalls or with a secure high level implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would appreciate, if you could suggest anything, that I could include in my post, in order to be better. Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Since this question appears to be about password hashing, [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) is good for theory. I don't have a good implementation at hand, but `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with a random per-user salt and at least 10000 iterations is a decent choice. For encryption I don't know a good article, but jbtule's answer at [Encrypt and decrypt a string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/445517) looks secure to me.